# Advice around method implementing an extended interface

Tags: java, aspectj, instanceof

I am trying to do an advice around a method that extends an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface StructureService {
    void delete(FileEntry entry);
}

public interface FileService extends StructureService {
     void dummy();
}
```

The classes that implement these looks like the following:

```
public class DbStructureService implements StructureService {
    public void delete(FileEntry entry) {
    }
}
public class DbFileService extends DbStructureService implements FileService {
    public void dummy() {
    }
}
```

I am trying to match the delete method, but only for classes implementing FileService.

I have defined the following aspect:

```
public aspect FileServiceEventDispatcherAspect {
    pointcut isFileService() : within(org.service.FileService+);

    pointcut delete(FileEntry entry) :
        execution(void org.service.StructureService.delete(..))
        && args(entry) && isFileService();

    void around(FileEntry entry) : delete(entry)  {
            proceed(entry);
    }
}
```

The problem is that as long as I have the isFileService pointcut enabled this will match no classes; even though there are plenty of methos that should match this

If I replace the within `within(org.service.FileService+)` to `within(org.service.StructureService+)` it also works fine.

I have tried experimenting with this() and so on but no success. How do I do this in aspectj?

EDIT:
Updated how the classes look that implements the interfaces. I think this scenario might be hard to advice since there is no overridden method in DbFileService

Comment: I am using binary compile time weaving if this matters

Comment: For compile time source code weaving this code is correct. May be the problem is in "binary", although there shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question. Do you think this is a scenario that isnt supported by aspectj? There is no real function to advice in the child class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean DbFileService implements FileService but not StructureService. Given that, this code should work:

```
public aspect FileServiceEventDispatcherAspect {    

pointcut delete(FileService this_, FileEntry entry) :
    execution(void org.service.StructureService.delete(..))
    && args(entry) && this(this_);

void around(FileService this_, FileEntry entry) : delete(this_, entry)  {
        proceed(this_, entry);
}
}
```

The "within" pointcut isn't suitable here because it is "lexical-structure based pointcut" (["AspectJ in Action", second edition.](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/))

Comment: Thanks, the reason I got confused is that there seems to be an error in eclipse AJDT. The markers show a match for all signatures regarding of the type of this. However when compiling it works.

Comment: AJDT is very useful but at the same time isn't very reliable. It could miss markers where advices are actually exist, give warnings about "advice has not been applied", etc.